# Differentiation of $\dfrac{d(\sin x)^{\ln x}}{dx}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, derivatives

> What is the value of $\dfrac{d(\sin x)^{\ln x}}{dx}$?

My attempt:

I applied chain rule in the following maner:

$$\frac{d\sin(x)^{\ln x}}{d\ln x}\cdot \frac{d(\ln x)}{dx} = \ln x\sin x^{\ln x -1} \cdot \frac{1}{x}$$

However my answer doesn't match with the one given in the key. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: $y = (\sin x)^{\ln x} \implies \ln y = \ln x \ln \sin(x) \implies \frac{y'}{y} = \frac{d}{dx}[\ln x \ln \sin(x)]$.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\frac d {dx} (\sin x)^{\ln x} = \frac d {dx} (e^{\ln\sin x})^{\ln x} = \frac d {dx} e^{(\ln\sin x)(\ln x)} = \cdots
$$
Here you can use the chain rule and the product rule.

Comment: +1! I recommend the OP use your method, which is more rigorous and systematic, rather than in the comments. Sad to say, many calculus books use that way, and the solution often became ugly and nonrigorous. (Some patient and perspective beginners wouldn't feel such solution comfortable)

Answer (score 2):

You've already received answers showing how to do it **right**. But let me also explain what you did **wrong**. The wrong part was your "derivative"
$$\frac{d\sin(x)^{\ln x}}{d\ln x}\stackrel{??}=\color{red}{\ln x\sin x^{\ln x-1}}.$$

You applied the so-called *Power Rule* here:
$$\frac{d}{dx}x^n=nx^{n-1},$$
which is only applicable when **the exponent is constant**. But in your case it isn't constant (it's $\ln(x)$, with respect to which you're taking the derivative), so this rule cannot be applied here.

Note that you can't treat this function as an exponential function either, because the base $\sin(x)$ isn't constant: as confusing as this sounds, due to the approach you chose, $\sin(x)$ is not constant with respect to $\ln(x)$.